# How do I get my generic class to require its parameters to extend/implement multiple classes?

Tags: java

I'm looking for the correct syntax for the following:

```
public class Foobar<K extends SomeJavaAPIClass and implements Cloneable>{
```

So that I can have Foobars of 'K', where K is a generic subclass of SomeJavaAPIClass and where K has it's own clone() method

I've tried `<K extends SomeJavaAPIClass, implements Cloneable>` with no luck, along with other permutations

Comment: Why would you care if it implemented `Cloneable` (evil interface anyway)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `&`:

```
public class Foobar<K extends SomeJavaAPIClass & Cloneable> {
```

Note that in generic wildcards, "extends" just means "is a subtype of", so you use it for either classes or interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

I think the following is valid:

```
public class Foobar<K extends SomeJavaAPIClass & Cloneable> {
```

As far as I know "extends" is used for both classes and interfaces in generic declarations.
Would someone else care to comment?